# Form filling helper

Tags: forms

I want to program a "form filling helper" with PHP, which fills out forms on different websites, but does not send the form (it should be proved manually, if everything is correct).

I read that cURL can fill out forms and send them, but I want to check them first, before they are sent.

Is this possible in PHP?

Thanks for suggestions!

Comment: PHP is server-side. You can't "fill out a form" with PHP.

Comment: Generally speaking, no.  You can't use PHP/cURL to fill a form on a remote site without submitting it.  It could be possible if the site explicitly permitted prefilling a form by essentially submitting it in an incomplete state, but this is unlikely.

Comment: You can use curl to simulate SUBMITTING a form to a server, by recreating the form's fieldnames/values. But curl is not a browser and can't actually fill in a form.

Answer (score 1):

Mike & Frank are correct. You would need something which would pre-fill the form for you in the browser, so you need to start looking at the browser side. Maybe some kind of browser add-on or plugin. Try to go through Firefox add-ons first.